# Upgrade MAMP MySQL to 5.7 on Windows

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP PRO 3.2.2 for Windows and need to upgrade the current MySQL version (5.5) to 5.7. Is there a way to do this in Windows?

Comment: did you ever solve this? im in the same position :(

Comment: @Jonnygogo no, i worked around it :S

Comment: I managed to get this working using WAMP instead. you have to go back and download 1.7.7

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it appears the only solution is updating MAMP. Which is a problem for me because the newest MAMP appears unstable (shutting servers on and off causes overlapping ports). I wish there was as I prefer MAMP 3.3.1.